# Plural Possessive of Surnames

Tags: punctuation, orthography, possessives

For the plural possessive of a surname, would you concur that these are correct?

the Rogerses' house
(surname is 'Rogers')
or should it be "the Rogers' house" for the plural possessive because 'Rogerses' is awkward?

the Hastingses' property
(surname is 'Hastings')
or should it be "the Hastings' property"for the plural possessive because 'Hastingses' is awkward?

Correct to these four?

> the Williamses' property line
>
> the Kennedys' house
>
> the Joneses' dog
>
> the Goronskys' pool

And lastly, would the following be a possessive or descriptive? 1 or 2?

> (1) the Stevenses' family tree
>
> (2) the Stevens family tree

A big and appreciative thanks.

Comment: This question has been asked many many times. Did you attempt a search?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the BNC (British National Corpus), and found the example:

> ...but he had been a frequent visitor at the Stevenses' home...

I think you can use both variants. In one way, you can leave *Rogers* or modify to *Rogerses* because *Rogers* is already carries in a way the plural meaning as it is the family, which consists of several persons, name. *Rogers* can be considered as the family entity (singular). Thus, the possesive case would be *Rogers'house*(adding the apostrophe) or *Rogerses'house*. The same is applied for *Hastings'property*, *Williams' property line*, *Kennedy'house*, *Jones' dog*, *the Goronsky' pool*.

Comment: The same for 'Hastingses' (should be 'Hastings' for the plural possessive)? And what about the 'Stevenses' query?